# Kindle Fire getting current location

Tags: android, location, kindle-fire, mapquest

I am using a Kindle Fire 2nd Gen which uses WiFi for it's location services.

The problem is I cannot seem to get this in-app. I am using the `LocationManager` in the version for Google Play which works fine, but for the Kindle it never returns a location just gets stuck using:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Is this because it is a Google service not available for the Kindle? Is there something else I can use.

I am using `MapQuest` but do not want to display a map overlay of the users location, I just want the current Lat and Long.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe the kindle has a GPS receiver so you cannot use Android `LocationManager` with it.

You can use the `MyLocationOverlay` class which is part of the `com.amazon.geo.maps` package in the [Amazon maps API](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/maps.html).  The [FAQ's](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/maps/faq.html) are decent and provide some good info.

Also, I haven't used it but [Skyhook](http://www.skyhookwireless.com/location-technology/index.php) provides a location SDK that might be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the Skyhook suggestion, I used that in the end and it works well. Its frustrating that Amazon do not provide a function for getting the location. Developers don't always want to display the location on the map. For instance I am passing the lat and long into a URL query string to get a JSON feed back and do not need a map.

Comment: It is. But I think Amazon wasn't expecting a big use case for the kindle being used as a GPS device. Oh well. I'm glad I could help. Good luck!

Comment: Yup sorry, completely forgot! Thanks

Comment: You CAN use LocationManager with the Kindle.  MyLocationOverlay actually implements the LocationManager class.  You can check the Amazon Maps API documentation.  You can use LocationManager, but use Network Provider instead of GPS Provider.  The fire phone should have GPS so if you're writing Kindle apps you should include both and check for isProviderEnabled().